# gsource_nm VARCHAR2(1024) := '$Source: /var/opt/pat/iisi/src/plsql/p_autoeph_hpe.sql,v $';

Tags: plsql

```
gsource_nm    VARCHAR2(1024) := '$Source: /var/opt/pat/iisi/src/plsql/p_autoeph_hpe.sql,v $';
```

I am not able to understand this line of code written in PLSQL programming language, especially the below command statement:

```
'$Source: /var/opt/pat/iisi/src/plsql/p_autoeph_hpe.sql,v $'
```

What does it actually relate or reflect to?

Comment: It declares a variable and at the same time assigns a value to it.

Answer (score 1):

#### A (old school) Source Code Management technique

It looks like this is a line automatically updated by your source manager software (e.g. git, Clearcase, SVN).

Here we asked the developers to have similar snippets in their code, like

```
gsource_nm    VARCHAR2(1024) := '$Source$';
```

or

```
FUNCTION ClearCase_VERSION RETURN VARCHAR2
IS
   w_id  VARCHAR2(1024) := '$Id$';
BEGIN
   RETURN 'Clearcase version number: '||w_id;
END VERSION;
```

Then at **commit time**, the source is modified by pattern search, and includes

- in your case, the path of the source
- in our case, the version of the source ; then it becomes something like

  ```
     w_id  VARCHAR2(1024) := '$Id: @(#) /vob/totosrc/MOMO.sql/main/19 17/07/2015 13:32:48 ju checkin $';
  ```

The variable is then used in a function that would be available in each package, to know exactly what version is installed on the current environment.

In your case, it allows to know where the source is in case it is necessary to modify it.

Answer (score 0):

This line of code is declaring a variable called `gsource_nm`. This variable is of type `VARCHAR2` (string) with a length of 1024

It then assigns the static string  `'$Source: /var/opt/pat/iisi/src/plsql/p_autoeph_hpe.sql,v $'` into the variable.

So at this stage the statement that you have queried does nothing.

We would need to see how the `gsource_nm` variable is used later in the code to be able to assist you in what this is actually doing.